# Why in final image of yocto asterisk is not available?

Tags: asterisk, yocto

I included meta-telephony in build/conf/bblayers and ran a 'bitbake asterisk' and the image is built successfully.But when i flash the image in SDcard I can't see any asterisk file or folder in the final image anywhere (/etc/asterisk or /usr/include/asterisk.h).

However in **build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/asterisk/** is available.

I tried including **IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "asterisk"** in local.conf but no change.What should I do to include asterisk in yocto.

I am building yocto for **"Raspberry Pi-2"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " asterisk". Mind there is a space after ".